# Python - find words starting and ending with vowel in dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to find in a `dataframe` column the words that start and end with vowel.

I couldn't find the `regex` way to (1) find all the words starting with vowel.
I just could find words that starts with a certain vowel.

Here is the `code` I used:-

```
# import the CSV file
sales_data = pd.read_csv ("data/sales-data.csv")

#Words starting with 'A'. This works
Vowels1 = sales_data[sales_data['CUSTOMERNAME'].str.startswith('A')]

#Words starting with vowel. This doesn't work. Why?
Vowels2 = sales_data[sales_data['CUSTOMERNAME'].str.startswith(r'[aeiouAEIOU]')]
```

How can I add the condition that starts and ends (at the same time) with vowel?

```
#This should work, but it doesn't.
Vowels3 = sales_data[sales_data['CUSTOMERNAME'].str.startswith(r'^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$')]
```

```
The message I get for Vowels2 and Vowels3 is:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ORDERID, ORDERPRICE, ORDERDATE, STATUS, PRODUCTLINE, PRODUCTCODE, CUSTOMERNAME, CITY, COUNTRY]
Index: []
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.contains` here:

```py
Vowels3 = sales_data[sales_data['CUSTOMERNAME'].str.contains(r'^[aeiou].*[aeiou]\.?$', flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Comment: Add sample data to your question.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I tried and realized that not all the names which fulfill the condition are shown. I changed a bit the code to include those words which end with dot: '''Vowels = sales_data[sales_data['CUSTOMERNAME'].str.contains(r'^[aeiou].*[aeiou|\.]$', flags=re.IGNORECASE)]'''
How can I set the condition that ends in vowel OR vowel + '.'?

Comment: IIUC, you want this regex pattern: `^[aeiou].*[aeiou]\.?$`

Comment: this is what you already mentioned first. Some names still appear, which, shouldn't: Australian Collectors, Co.' -> OK // 'UK Collectables, Ltd.' -> NOK
 'Australian Gift Network, Co' -> OK // 'Amica Models & Co.' -> OK// 'Auto Assoc. & Cie.' ->OK. Ending with vowel+(dot) is ok, ending with (dot) isn't ok. I've been trying other options but they don't work. Thanks!

Comment: The pattern I have given you _only_ matches customer names ending in a vowel or vowel followed by a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Startswith and Endswith accept tuples, so you can use those:

```
vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')
if myword.startswith(vowels) and myword.endswith(vowels):
    print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

Becasue you are intersted only on the first and last letters, you don't need the `regexp` overhead or even the `startwith` which looking for sequence.

Instead you can just `apply` on the column the lambda `lam` as:

```
v = ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')
lam = lambda word: word[0] in v and word[-1] in v
```

Please note that the case of empty string is not handled here